# How would one integrate ReCaptcha in to BlogEngine.net (ASP.net C#)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, recaptcha, blogengine.net

I am trying to figure out how to best integrate the ReCaptcha API with BlogEngine.net. If there is anyone that has done this -- how did you do it?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

[Using reCaptcha with BlogEngine.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260525/using-recaptcha-with-blogengine-net)

Even better, I followed this post and was able to integrate recaptcha into my blogengine.net blog quite nicely.

http://www.keithratliff.com/post/adding-recaptcha-to-blogenginenet.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is now included as part of Blogengine.net 1.6.1