# Using reCaptcha with BlogEngine.net

Tags: recaptcha

I have just installed reCaptcha on my site and put the control on my comment post, so far so good.

Now to validate reCaptcha it says just do Page.IsValid.

However BlogEngine uses Ajax and some JS to post its addComment function and if I test that there I just get error on page in the status bar.

Here is the bloengine post function -

```
/// <summary>
/// Processes a callback event that targets a control.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="eventArgument">A string that represents an event argument to pass to the event handler.</param>
public void RaiseCallbackEvent(string eventArgument)
{
    if (!BlogSettings.Instance.IsCommentsEnabled)
        return;

    string[] args = eventArgument.Split(new string[] { "-|-" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    string author = args[0];
    string email = args[1];
    string website = args[2];
    string country = args[3];
    string content = args[4];
    bool notify = bool.Parse(args[5]);
    bool isPreview = bool.Parse(args[6]);
    string sentCaptcha = args[7];
    //If there is no "reply to" comment, args[8] is empty
    Guid replyToCommentID = String.IsNullOrEmpty(args[8]) ? Guid.Empty : new Guid(args[8]);

    string storedCaptcha = hfCaptcha.Value;

    Comment comment = new Comment();
    comment.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    comment.ParentId = replyToCommentID;
    comment.Author = Server.HtmlEncode(author);
    comment.Email = email;
    comment.Content = Server.HtmlEncode(content);
    comment.IP = Request.UserHostAddress;
    comment.Country = country;
    comment.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
    comment.Parent = Post;
    comment.IsApproved = !BlogSettings.Instance.EnableCommentsModeration;

    if (Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        comment.IsApproved = true;

    if (website.Trim().Length > 0)
    {
        if (!website.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("://"))
            website = "http://" + website;

        Uri url;
        if (Uri.TryCreate(website, UriKind.Absolute, out url))
            comment.Website = url;
    }

    if (notify && !Post.NotificationEmails.Contains(email))
        Post.NotificationEmails.Add(email);
    else if (!notify && Post.NotificationEmails.Contains(email))
        Post.NotificationEmails.Remove(email);

    if (!isPreview)
    {
        Post.AddComment(comment);
        SetCookie(author, email, website, country);
    }

    string path = Utils.RelativeWebRoot + "themes/" + BlogSettings.Instance.Theme + "/CommentView.ascx";

    CommentViewBase control = (CommentViewBase)LoadControl(path);
    control.Comment = comment;
    control.Post = Post;

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        control.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(sw));
        _Callback = sw.ToString();
    }
}
```

I tried just putting if(!Page.IsValid) return; but that never worked.

Comment: Can you please post the ASPX and any ASPX.CS code that is related to the captcha? I'm fairly familiar with DNBE as I have my personal blog using it, and have written a few extensions for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now 1.6.1 has inbuilt support for reCaptcha
See
[Enable ReCaptcha](http://blogengine.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=EnablingRecaptcha)

Answer (score 2):

reCaptcha's default API does not work with AJAX-driven webpages, especially when you replace the content, where the reCaptcha resides. The problem here is the default reCaptcha API. Just switch to the AJAX API, which is also offered [here](http://recaptcha.net/apidocs/captcha/client.html)

Comment: If I only use the Ajax API wouldn't spammers be able to just disable JS and that would bypass it?

Comment: I guess I should check the BlogEngine code and see if there is a normal post method for comments and put the default API in there?

Comment: The page submit with ajax pages would not work, if you disable JS so it would not be bypassed. I would go for the ajax API (as i did with one of my sites).

Answer (score 1):

```
var captchaChallengeValue = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["recaptcha_challenge_field"];
var captchaResponseValue = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["recaptcha_response_field"];
var captchaValidator = new Recaptcha.RecaptchaValidator
{
    PrivateKey = "private key here",
    RemoteIP = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress,
    Challenge = captchaChallengeValue,
    Response = captchaResponseValue
};

var recaptchaResponse = captchaValidtor.Validate();
```

This is how I did it on a different site.  I took what was entered and the response and then created a new captchaValidator which has a method that will check if the responses are valid.  Then use that as your boolean for your if.

I am using ASP.Net MVC.  But, I would assume that the idea is similar.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I treid this and though I think your code is correct (I checked the debugger) if I return false from my comment method the page breaks due to a JS error.

I don't know if this is a problem with what return1.at said in the post above.

Comment: I'm sure that that is the issue.  I just know that I tried to validate my captcha the same way you did and I had to do it this way to get the boolean I needed.  Was just hoping that it would get you going in the right direction.